# glTexImage2D causes GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: ios, opengl-es

This is my (wrapped) OpenGL call which causes a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`:

```
GLTextures.TexImage2D(TexImage2DTarget.TEXTURE_2D, 0, TexImageInternalFormat.LUMINANCE_ALPHA, Width, Height, TexImageFormat.LUMINANCE_ALPHA, TexImagePixelType.UNSIGNED_BYTE, source.GetData());
```

This call works on Windows but not on iOS, in Windows everything works fine and the texture is displayed. I use the same enum-values on iOS and Windows and even the shader is the same ( with some precision hints on iOS ). Also the most textures are working on iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue by thinking about the fact that it runs on desktop but not on iOS. OpenGL textures using a `format` and `internal format` and are AFAIK converted from one to another format when the formats are different but the OpenGL ES 2.0 implementation of Apple isn't supporting this.

It came in my mind that this can be the only issue for the not working textures and the `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. I checked my enums and found out that the definition of `LUMINANCE_ALPHA` in one enum had no value assigned and just used the number of the definition before + 1. OpenGL ignores this on desktop because the number has been a valid texture format, on iOS it fails.

Answer (score 3):

Luminance alpha textures use *LATC* texture compression.

And because iPhone doesn't support `EXT_texture_compression_latc` extension you can't use *LATC* textures on iPhone.

More info:

http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_compression_latc.txt

http://www.glbenchmark.com/phonedetails.jsp?benchmark=glpro25&D=Apple+iPhone+5&testgroup=gl

Comment: But the specs say: `The most important reason to make these new compressed formats
        show up identically to conventional luminance and luminance-alpha
        texels is to allow applications to seamlessly substitute
        the new compressed formats for existing GL_LUMINANCE and
        GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA textures.` Also the quick reference card shows that it is supported: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf

Comment: Please note that internal formats of textures are not necessarily supported by any given GPU (PowerVR in your case). OpenGL driver might try to convert luminance-alpha texture to some supported internal format but on mobile devices drivers usually don't do this. I don't work with iPhone but on Android I always check if certain texture format is supported by checking GL extensions and then load texture of proper format. Please excuse me for viewing your problem from somewhat another (Android) point of view, on iPhone OpenGL drivers can be better.

Comment: No problem, thank you. But i thought it should work. It's hard to find ppl who faced the same issue on iOS.

Comment: I don't actually see where he uses a compressed texture format **at all**. He uses the good old `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` internal format which doesn't neccessarily imply any compression. If OpenGL ES behaves differently from desktop GL in this regard, please add that to your answer, because at least in desktop GL he doesn't use any kind of compressed texture storage. See your linked extension spec for the `COMPRESSED_LUMINANCE_ALPHA_LATC2_EXT` format he would have used for compressed texture storage.

Comment: According to the OpenGL ES 1.0 specification (and I doubt later versions to degrade in this regard), OpenGL ES perfectly supports the good old `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` internal format which, again, doesn't use any kind of texture compression or any extension per se. If you got other information please provide some references.

Comment: If this format is mapped internally to some kind of compressed format then that can only happen opaque to the client and inside the limits of the spec. The ES device cannot just map the to be supported `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` format to a compressed LATC format only to realize that it cannot actually support this mapped format. *"Hey, when trying to use luminance alpha we better use latc, but well, we don't have latc, so no luminance alpha for you"*. That would be ridiculous.

Comment: @ChristianRau Thank you for clarifying this. Now I see that my answer is misleading.